# Github actions token workflow not set error

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, building-github-actions, github-token

Hello everyone I am currently writing a workflow to auto merge when a pull request is made but I am stuck at an error telling me my token is not set more specifically: **2023-02-19T02:09:08.581Z ERROR environment variable GITHUB_TOKEN not set!**.  I have set all my tokens in my repo and settings tab. Any help would be appreciated.

```
name: CI/CD 

on: 
  pull_request: 
    branches: [ master ]  
    
jobs: 
  super-linter:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Super-Linter
        uses: github/super-linter@v4.10.1
        with:    
          files: ${{ join(github.event.pull_request.changed_files, ',') }}
          
  Merge:       
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest       
    needs: super-linter
    steps:   
      - name: Checkout Code 
        uses: actions/checkout@v2 
      - name: Merge pull requests 
        uses: pascalgn/automerge-action@v0.14.1   
        with: 
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
      
        
  deploy: 
    runs-on: self-hosted   
    needs: Merge
    steps: 
      #- uses: actions/checkout@v2  #this is used for if you want to push all source code into runner       
      - name: update code base 
        working-directory: /test_pipe/www/html 
        run: sudo git pull origin master        
      - name: restart   
        working-directory: /test_pipe/www/html
        run: sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0eMH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pascalgn/automerge-action`](https://github.com/pascalgn/automerge-action) accepts `GITHUB_TOKEN` as an env variable, not as an argument. So it should be:

```
  - name: Merge pull requests 
    uses: pascalgn/automerge-action@v0.14.1   
    env: 
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
```

Refer to the documentation: https://github.com/pascalgn/automerge-action#usage